# React Function Component should use : var functionName = function() {} or function functionName() {}

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and referring to multiple sources to understand concepts

For *React Function Components* declaration; I've found 2 ways

1st way

```
var functionOne = function() {
    // Some code
};
```

2nd way

```
function functionTwo() {
    // Some code
}
```

which one is recommended ?

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation uses the second type.

https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html